# EF Select all or matching string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

This is what I'm trying to do if I were using plain SQL

1. User selected "All"

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '%'
   ```
2. User selected particular name

   ```
   SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE 'John'
   ```

In EF, the closest translation of a like query seems to be contains. So I do something like this:

```
string comboboxValue = getComboboxValue(); //Empty if all selected

from tb in _dbContext.TABLE
where tb.NAME.Contains(comboboxValue)
select COLUMN
```

Which works fine for retrieving all. However, using Contains would mean that the above would match "Johnathan", not just "John"

Is there a way of getting the exact same behavior desired?

Comment: `LIKE '%pattern%'` will match `pattern1` and `pattern`. `LIKE 'pattern'` will match only `pattern`. `%` - is a wildcard in `LIKE` clause. If you selecting all, you don't need `WHERE` at all! If you select without wildcard, you don't need `LIKE`, use `=`

Comment: @Alexander Precisely. In your example, I want to only match 'pattern' or if specified, '%'. In particular, I don't want '%pattern%', but with the contains method, this seems impossible to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A like query uses the `%` as a wildcard. So while you would never want to search for `WHERE NAME LIKE '%'` (since this just returns everything), you can use `%` to search for a pattern:

1. `Where Name like 'John%'` matches all rows where the name *starts with* 'John'
2. `Where Name like '%john'` matches all rows where Name *ends with* 'John'
3. `Where Name like '%john%'` matches all rows where Name has 'john' somewhere inside of the column

Using Entity Framework, you can match these different search types:

1. Return where Name starts with 'John': `.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("John"));`
2. Return where Name ends with 'John': `.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("John"));`
3. Return where Name has 'John' anywhere inside: `.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("John"));`
4. Return where Name equals 'John': `.Where(x => x.Name == "John");`
5. Do not filter on name: (just don't use a where clause for this)

In your original sql as well, you would want to avoid using `Like` when you are not using wildcards. If you want to match an exact value, use `=`. If you don't want to filter, then just don't include the `where` clause.

For your specific situation, you would want to see what the comboBox value is, and proceed accordingly:

```
string comboboxValue = getComboboxValue(); //Empty if all selected
var isAll = string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboboxValue)
return _dbContext.Table.Where(x => isAll || x.Name == comboBoxValue).Select(x => x.COLUMN);
```

It doesn't look like you would have any need to use `Contains` or any of the other wildcard searches that you referred to.

Comment: This appears to be not what OP asked

Comment: No, I want to retrieve either everything or only rows matching the search term

Comment: @l46kok just fixed the logic. If `comboboxValue` is empty, then `isAll` is true and all rows are returns. If `comboboxValue` is not empty or null, then it will only return rows that match the search term.

Comment: if you string is tshirt then it will be returned for shirt

Answer (score 0):

You could use some signaling variable to opt for one way or the other like

`bool matchExact = false;`
`...`
`where tb.NAME == ( matchExact ? comboboxValue : tb.NAME )`
`...`

Mind nulls though